# Scala: Custom compiler warning

Tags: java, scala, annotations

I've created a trait with some abstract procedures (methods returning Unit). I've then created a sub trait that puts in dummy implementations {} for the convenience of development. However I want to put a compiler warning on the dummy trait: "Using the dummy trait all functionality may not be implemented. Use the base trait in production."

I've looked at the Scala annotations and the Java annotations and I can't find an appropriate annotation or way of doing this. I could just make use of a deprecated annotation, but that's rather inelegant:

```
@deprecated("GraphicMethodsDummy contains procedure stubs. Inherit from GraphicMethods for production", "")
```

Inheriting from deprecated doesn't seem to have much advantage as the method that produces the compiler message seems to be private and can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Change your API so that the dummy trait can only be obtained through a "creator" method (e.g in a companion object).**
2. **Implement the "creator method" as [a def macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).** It would look something like this:

---

```
class Dummy

object creator {
    def apply(): Dummy = macro creatorImpl

    def creatorImpl(c: Context)(): c.Expr[Dummy] = {
        import c.universe._

        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition,
            """Using the dummy trait all functionality may not be implemented. 
                        Use the base trait in production.""")

        reify(new Dummy)
    }
}
```

---

Note that an alternative, less involved way that is commonly used in various APIs (like Guava) is to just add a custom annotation to your class (e.g. `@NotSafeForProd`). However, this will of course not generate a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

If regular deprecation isn't good enough, how about rolling your own:

```
package scala {
  class noProd extends deprecatedInheritance("Provide an impl for production", since="forever")
}

package dummyonly {

  trait Abs { def f(i: Int): String }

  @noProd
  class Dummy extends Abs {
    def f(i: Int) = i.toString
  }
}
```

In a separate compilation unit:

```
//dummyonly2.scala:3: warning: inheritance from class Dummy in package dummyonly is deprecated: Provide an impl for production

package dummyonly {
  class Mine extends Dummy
}
```

Edit:

The privileged annotation is private to `scala`, but it's so useful that it's criminal to hide it under a bushel.

I don't really know, but the code comment reads:

```
// for now, this needs to be generalized to communicate other modifier deltas
```

or, to coin a phrase, WTF? I know what a "modifier" is, but a "modifier delta" is beyond my ken.  The comment suggests, though, that the annotation might see broader access when they figure out how to make it work in a maintainable way.

I think there's supposed to be a semicolon instead of a comma, i.e., "for now; ...", but Scala programmers are so programmed to avoid semicolons that they avoid them even when grammatically correct.

Comment: Although internally arguably a bit "hacky", this solution is more readable and overall better for end-users than a macro; that is, if the usage pattern conforms to what the OP is after, *and* if it's a temporary measure (since you're essentially using undocumented internal API). The answer would benefit from an explanation of why there's a `scala` package declaration.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Added metacomment.  I agree, I wasn't sure what the OP wanted, so I made something up.